# custom action string type dependency property error

Tags: custom-actions

I am writing a custom action and running into an error on the publish stage of the SPD workflow editor.

Essentially, my problem is that my dependency properties are not working correctly. Half of them do work without error--but I have two properties that are strings that are causing the error.

In the activity class:

```
public static DependencyProperty StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(emailaction));
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Description("Status")]
public string Status
{
    get { return ((string)(base.GetValue(emailaction.StatusProperty))); }
    set { base.SetValue(emailaction.StatusProperty, value); }
}
```

In the actions file:

```
<Parameter Name="Status" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" />
```

Is there anything glaringly wrong here that is causing the error? Both my string dependency properties are causing problems, but my "int" and "WorkflowContext" properties are not returning errors.

EDIT:
After further investigation, I had two errors happening at the same time and assumed they were the same problem. There is actually no problem with the above code, I made the mistake of testing this *without filling in a value.* I am in fact having issues pulling in the list ID properly, but I will look into this further before posting a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The code given above was returning a workflow error simply because I did not fill in a value before trying to check the workflow. The other field that's giving me issues will need to be investigated further.